# Publish WCF Service in IIS with support for both HTTP and HTTPS

Tags: wcf, http, iis, https

I have a WCF-Service configured with two endpoints using webHttpBinding, one for http and the other for https. They use the same address, the endpoints just differ by the used protocol:

`<services>

    <service name="Blubb.ClientService">

        <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webBindingConfig" behaviorConfiguration="webBehaviour" 
contract="Blubb.Contracts.IClientService"/>

        <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="sslWebBindingConfig" behaviorConfiguration="webBehaviour" 
contract="Blubb.Contracts.IClientService"/>
      </service>

<services>`

using the following behaviours and bindings:

`<behaviors>

  <endpointBehaviors>

    <behavior name="webBehaviour">

      <webHttp/>

    </behavior>

  </endpointBehaviors>

</behaviors>

    <bindings>

      <webHttpBinding>

        <binding name="webBindingConfig">

          <security mode="None"/>

        </binding>

        <binding name="sslWebBindingConfig">

          <security mode="Transport"/>

        </binding>

      </webHttpBinding>

    </bindings>`

Both endpoints work fine when I have the certificate installed on IIS 6.

When the certificate is not installed, the HTTPS-Endpoint certainly won't work. But the HTTP-Endpoint doesn't work either. It fails with an irritating exception: when I access the service with http://localhost:8080/ClientManagement/ClientService.svc/GetPackageInfo the exception is:

`Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the endpoint with binding WebHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http].`

which is irritating because I didn't request an HTTPS-URL.

Now when I split the service into two, the HTTP-Access also works on the IIS on which the SSL-Certificate is not installed:

`<services>

<service name="Blubb.ClientService">
        <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webBindingConfig" behaviorConfiguration="webBehaviour" 
contract="Blubb.Contracts.IClientService"/>

</service>

<service name="Blubb.ClientServiceSecure">

<endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="sslWebBindingConfig" behaviorConfiguration="webBehaviour" 
contract="Blubb.Contracts.IClientService"/>

</service>

</services>`

The problem now is that the client has to use two different endpoints instead of just changing the protocol. We have a system where the customer can turn on SSL via our Configuration-Tool depending on their security needs. But I don't want to force them to change the web.config of the WCF-Service.

Comment: See this duplicate question(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908138/cant-get-wcf-to-use-both-http-and-https-for-an-operation) and response

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't get WCF to use both http and https for an operation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908138/cant-get-wcf-to-use-both-http-and-https-for-an-operation)

Comment: I don't think that it's a duplicate. My question is if there is a way to support HTTPS optionally without changing the endpoint URL. We have a system where the customer can turn on SSL via our Configuration-Tool depending on their security needs. But I don't want to force them to change the web.config of the WCF-Service.